# no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin?

Tags: c++

simple program tells u how much milk costs whatever i dont get why i get this error "no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin??"   im a beginner at c++ but still what the hell.

also this error: "In function 'int main()':"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or      input loop */

const double CARTONLOAD = 3.78;
const double CARTONCOST = 3.78 * .38;
const double CARTONPROFIT = 0.27;

int main() 
{
    double totalmilk = 0;
    double milkcartonsneeded = 0;
    double milkcost = 0;

    cout << "Enter total amount of milk produced in the morning in Liters" << endl;
    cin >> totalmilk >> endl;
    milkcartonsneeded = totalmilk/CARTONLOAD;
    cout << " Number of milk cartons needed to hold milk: "  << milkcartonsneeded << endl;
    milkcost = milkcartonsneeded * CARTONCOST;
    cout << " The cost of producing milk is: " << milkcost << endl;
    cout << " The profit for producing milk is: " << milkcartonsneeded * CARTONPROFIT - milkcost << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`endl` is an output stream manipulator. `cin` is an input stream. I'm not sure what you expect `endl` to do here:

```
cin >> totalmilk >> endl;
```

But it's wrong.

Comment: @user3542679: That is correct. It causes the stream to output a new line (in addition to other things). But `cin` does not output anything. That's `cout`'s job.

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem

```
cin >> totalmilk >> endl;
```

It is giving error because of endl. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`operator<<` has an overload that takes a function pointer to a function that receives an `std::basic_ostream`. This allows you to use "stream manipulators", i.e. `std::endl`, in a `operator<<` chain. This allows you to do the following for example:

```
std::cout << "hey.";
std::endl(std::cout);
std::cout << "hello.";
```

Because `std::endl` is just a function that takes a `std::basic_ostream`. However, it also returns one by reference (similar to `operator<<`), meaning it can appear in a chain, i.e. `std::cout << std::endl`.

Since `std::cin` is a `std::basic_istream`, you have incompatible arguments.

Comment: The compiler never gets to the point of actually trying to resolve the call `std::endl(std::cin)`. The OP is using `operator>>` (not `operator<<`), and there is no overload which will work for `std::endl`.